# Параметры столбцов Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте, появилась очень глупая и неудобная проблема.

Пытаюсь создать миграцию, создал её тело и теперь с помощью неё хочу создать таблицу. Но вот появилась проблема - не могу найти, где почитать о параметрах столбцов, которые можно указывать.

Т.е.:

```
public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('faq', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'name' => $this->string(255),
        'text' => $this->text(),
        'important' => $this->integer(1),
    ]);
}
```

И вот участки, в которых задаются параметры столбца(тип данных, к примеру).

Как-то вообще мало нашёл, хотя искал:

- В статьях о работе с БД
- Несколько статей по миграциям
- Руководство по миграциям в оф.документации

Всё, что нашёл, это типы данных некоторые(string, text, integer) и primaryKey&unique. Где-то можно обширно почитать об параметрах, которые можно задавать?

---

И что делать, если некоторых типов данных там нет? К примеру, tinytext? Указывать, как строку?

Comment: Хм, нашёл тела функций в vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\SchemaBuilderTrait.php.

В принципе, всё понятно. Но, возможно, есть текстовая документация? В будущем для тех, кто пришёл с поисковых систем и не хочет/нет возможности покопаться в коде.

Answer (score 1):

Это всего лишь один вариант записи миграции.
Типы колонок можно задавать и стоками.
Выражения типа `$this->primaryKey()` в результате тоже превращаются в строки.

Можете посмотреть существующие методы тут: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-schemabuildertrait.html